# PyQt TabWidget not displaying ui or accepting setCurrentWidget

Tags: python, path, pyqt, qtabwidget

I've been working on an application for work and have run into a bit of a quandary. The following code will successfully add a new tab to my tabWidget, set the title of the tab, load an external ui, generate a file or preview a file when one of two buttons is pressed, and will be set to the current tab when it opens from a menu acion:

```
def strap6_gui(self): #Create new tab and load TMS6 Strapping UI
    self.strap6 = QtGui.QWidget(self.tabWidget)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.strap6, 'TMS6 Tank Strapping')
    uic.loadUi(strap6, self.strap6)
    self.strap6.strap6_generate.clicked.connect(self.strap6_func)
    self.strap6.strap6_previewButton.clicked.connect(self.strap6_prev)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.strap6)
```

The problem is this: the following code, which was copied from the above and modified slightly, doesn't do what it's supposed to. It will open a new tab and set the title, but this new tab doesn't get set to the current tab or load the ui file:

```
def txled_gui(self): #Create new tab and load TMS6 Strapping UI
    self.txled = QtGui.QWidget(self.tabWidget)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.txled, 'TMS6 Tank Strapping')
    uic.loadUi(txui, self.txled)
    self.txled.strap6_generate.clicked.connect(self.strap6_func)
    self.txled.strap6_previewButton.clicked.connect(self.strap6_prev)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.txled)
```

When I was working on this, I copied the strap6.ui and renamed it as txui.ui so I could tell if the tab was getting the information from the file location. The file locations are set as:

```
strap6 = os.path.abspath('.\UI\strap6_gui.ui')
txui = os.path.abspath('.\UI\txled_gui.ui')
```

I have a few other UI's that get loaded as popups that are in the same directory and called in the same fashion, so I know that cannot be the problem. Finally, here is the error messaging that shows up in the console when I run the application:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Seth\\Documents\\TSE\\pythonTesting\\TriadGUI\\UI\txled_gui.ui'
```

How come the first def works without fail but the second one, which was a copy of the first and setup w/ new names etc. doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself, I think.

`txui` has a tab in it because you did not escape the backslashes.

So you need:

```
txui = os.path.abspath(r'.\UI\txled_gui.ui')
```

or:

```
txui = os.path.abspath('.\\UI\\txled_gui.ui')
```

Comment: Interesting, changing the path to '.\\UI\\txled_gui.ui' worked; but now I'm curious, the following work fine as-is, without explicitly escaping the backslashes: `mainGUI = os.path.abspath('.\UI\Triad.ui')
scpGUI = os.path.abspath('.\UI\scp.ui')
gsGUI = os.path.abspath('.\UI\gsReports.ui')`

Comment: @SethKoberg. It's because there are no [recogized escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-15) in those strings. For _unrecognized_ escape sequences, the sequence (including the backslash) is left unchanged. Of course, the safest thing to do (especially with Windows path names) is to just escape all backslashes that need to be treated as literals.